Comportamiento extraño de IntelliJ IDE al cambiar de pestaña me reinicia todo
Tengo instalada la versión IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.0.2 (Ultimate Edition) en mi mac Apple M1 Pro, cuándo cambio de pestaña y vuelvo al IDE se me recarga todo, hasta ahora he hecho muchas cosas pero no entiendo que está pasando, necesito una ayuda.
Instalé nueva versión, borré el caché y revisé los logs pero sigue pasando.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Tal vez lo más sensato sería que grabes un video y contactes al soporte técnico de jetbrains. Tal vez quieras adicionalmente editar tu pregunta y explicar a que te refieres con cambiar de pestaña y volver al IDE, como usuario de windows no lo entiendo. saludos.

A lo que me refiero es que me salgo del IDE digamos a Chrome y cuando vuelo, en la parte de los proyectos se me desaparecen las carpetas que tengo y abajo en la esquina inferior derecha, sale indexando nuevamente, entonces es cómo si me recargara todo el proyecto nuevamente cada que hago lo anterior mencionado.
